# How to use the resetButton to reset parameters

Tags: java, swing

Im writing a program that deals with creating a house and rearranging the neighbors (similar to game of life)

It is written in Java and it as a Reset button to restart with the current parameters.

The problem is that when i click the resetButton the whole window closes.

You can find the code at the and of the question.

These are other involved fields, so you might be able to understand the code better:

- TextField to set the size of the city (number of squares on an edge).
- TextFild to set the maximum percentage of neighbors not-like-you that a household will tolerate before they move. I.e., if the number is set to 70, a red house hold with 6 blue neighbors will move; a red household with 5 blue neighbors is ok according to this.
- TextField to set a minimum percentage of neighbors not-like-you that a household will tolerate before they move. Make this greater than 0 for a person who LIKES diversity TextField to set the percentage of red households. Note: you can do this with probability. You do not need to have this exact percentage of red households.
- TextField to set the percentage of blue households. White will be what is left over. Single step button gives every household one chance to move. You do not need to be careful about that fact that, as you progress through the city, a person early in the move chances may move to a place that later gets a chance (i.e., some households really get two or more turns).
- Go button, to start and stop the program from doing steps on its own.

So my questions is how do i let those field and buttons restart with the current parameters ( restart it with what i have originally after playing a few times)

As you can see I added the resetButton to do its job but somehow it is not.

Ok it is like I run the program I have a set of numbers for red and blue as you can see in my, then when I run it it starts with those numbers. And so I keep on changing as i play, and then there is a reset button that lets me reset what I did and should bring back what it originally started with:

```
public final static int size = 5 and so on
```

This is my main program

```
public class Ghetto extends JFrame implements ActionListener,  MouseListener,MouseMotionListener 
   {

protected Grids theGrid;
JButton resetButton;
javax.swing.Timer timer; // generates ticks that drive the animation

public final static int SIZE = 5;
public final static int BLUE = 10;
public final static int RED = 8;
public final static int DIVERSITY_PERCENTAGE = 70;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Ghetto();

}

public Ghetto() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    theGrid = new Grids(SIZE, BLUE, RED, DIVERSITY_PERCENTAGE);
    add(theGrid);

    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    add(resetButton);
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            resetWithCurrent();
        }
    });


    setSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
    setVisible(true);
}



public void resetWithCurrent()
{
    //this.dispose();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            performStep();

                            //if (e.getSource() == resetButton )
                            //{
            //resetWithCurrent();
                            //}
        }
    });

}
}
```

Also I added this part

```
    public class Observable{

    int state = 0;
    int additionalState = 0;
    public final void updateState(int increment)
    {
        doUpdateState(increment);
        notifyObservers();
    }
    private void notifyObservers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void doUpdateState(int increment)
    {
        state = state + increment;      
    }

}
public class ConcreteObservable extends Observable{

public void doUpdateState(int increment){
        super.doUpdateState(increment); // the observers are notified
        additionalState = additionalState + increment; // the state is     changed after the notifiers are updated
    }

}
```

But it didnt make any difference.

Comment: A simple method would be to devise a model, which held the state of the game, allowing the view to update itself to represent the model. When you want to reset the game, you'd simply create a new model and apply it, allowing the view to the change

Comment: I am Not sure if I understood what you said, if you dont mind writing it in a code it would make much more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I'm talking about using a [model-view-control](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) and [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to link the various parts of the program and provide notifications when things change

Comment: Sorry I never used the model view control thing. I dont know how would that work.

Comment: Read the links. Separate the visual from the non-visual elements of your program, non-visual would become the model and represent the state of the program, the visual elements would represent the model visually and possibly change the state of the model.  The model would need to provide notification of changes to the state based on your needs, this would allow the visual elements to update them selves as required

Comment: I read it, I understand the English of it, I applied what I understood, but what is the problem with the code is what I am not getting.

Comment: I edit my post I made it clearer to what i need change with.